# How to do a table with fixed columns and cells spanning multiple columns?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn

I would like to do a table like this:

[image]

I have found how to fix the column  widths in: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef?rq=1), [How to create a table with fixed column widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286950/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-column-widths) and [Center a fixed width text within a multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302550/center-a-fixed-width-text-within-a-multicolumn) .

However, when I try to merge multiple cells together with multicolumn, the column width fails:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X|X|X|X}
    \toprule
    Activity & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1st year} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2nd year} \\
     & 1st semester & 2nd semester & 1st semester & 2nd semester  \\
    \midrule
    I. &  Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.
 & & \\
  II. &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.}
  & \\
  III. &  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**How can I manage to do a table with fixed columns and cells spanning multiple columns?**

Comment: Could you please post the code used?

Comment: @Bernard I updated the post with the code I tried.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue, but please keep in mind that horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package are intended to be used without vertical lines. This is thereason for the small gaps in the vertical lines around the intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With the help of `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}` in defined a new column type `L`. This column type is based on the `X` type, but its contents are left aligned instead of justified. (See also: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144))

In order to get the correct width for the `\multicolumn` cells, I used `>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}L`. Since the `\multicolumn` cell spans 3 `L` (or `X`) columns, we can start with `>{\hsize=3\hsize}L` (See also: [Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84400/134144)). To this, we then add `4\tabcolsep` (`\tabcolsep` is the small amount of horizontal white space that is added to either side of the text inside of a table cell) as well as `2\arrayrulewidth`(`\arrayrulewidth`is the width of the vertical lines in the table.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L|L|L|L|}
    \hline
    Activity & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1st year} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2nd year} \\ \cline{2-5}
     & 1st semester & 2nd semester & 1st semester & 2nd semester  \\
    \hline
    I. &  Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.
 & & &\\ \hline
  II. &  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}L|}{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.}
  & \\ \hline
  III. &  & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}L|}{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an entirely different approach based on the `pgfgantt` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}


\begin{document}

\noindent
     \begin{ganttchart}[
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=1.25cm,
     x unit =1.75cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title label font=\footnotesize,
     bar height=0.5,
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     bar label node/.style={text width=4.75cm,
                            align=right,
                            anchor=east,
                            font=\footnotesize\raggedleft}
    ]{1}{4}

  \gantttitle{1st year}{2}
  \gantttitle{2nd year}{2}         \\
  \gantttitle{1st semester}{1}
  \gantttitle{2st semester}{1}
  \gantttitle{1st semester}{1}
  \gantttitle{2st semester}{1}\\
  \ganttbar{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.}{1}{1}\\
  \ganttbar{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.}{1}{3}\\
    \ganttbar{Perform some experiment, do some calculations, write a report and present the results in a conference.}{2}{4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}` and `\multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep}L|}`. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Puco4: I added some short comments on both code pieces. I hope this helps. If you have some further questions, feel free to ask. I also added an entirely different approach based on the `pgfgantt` package.